# Adding and removing observers to NSNotificationCenter in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, dealloc, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

Looking at various Apple examples (for example [Add Music](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html)) in which I see they add observers to the default `NSNotificationCenter`  in `viewDidLoad`, then remove them in `dealloc`. This seems dangerous as `viewDidLoad` can be called multiple times without `dealloc` being called. This would then add the same observer multiple times, causing the handler to be called multiple times.

A solution to this would be to also remove observers in `viewDidUnload`, but this would then mean the same observer could be removed for a second time in `dealloc` which seems like a potential problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think removing an observer which doesn't exist has any adverse effect.

Comment: @jbat100 Thanks. I'm definitely thinking removing observers in both dealloc and viewDidUnload is the only way to go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21418937/3378413 Updated answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a lot of discussions about removing notifications in the right way. For example:

- [removeobserver-with-nsnotification-what-am-i-doing-wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328210/removeobserver-with-nsnotification-what-am-i-doing-wrong)
- [removing-a-nsnotificationcenter-observer-in-ios-5-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372841/removing-a-nsnotificationcenter-observer-in-ios-5-arc)

I suggest you to remove observers in `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisappear`) and `viewDidUnload` lifecycle methods. (**Note:** `viewDidUnload` was deprecated and shouldn't be implemented in iOS6+; see [iOS 6 - viewDidUnload migrate to didReceiveMemoryWarning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674268/ios-6-viewdidunload-migrate-to-didreceivememorywarning))

An important note:

`viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called - it's not a standard lifecycle method.

From Apple doc:

> viewDidUnload
>   When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s
>   views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from
>   memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has
>   been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup.

Instead, `dealloc` is called whenever the number of references for that receiver is zero.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

For the sake of completeness you can see this link on how to [avoid-nsnotification-removeobserver](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.it/2011/04/avoid-nsnotification-removeobserver.html). The link provide some useful guidelines to remove observer (see also the comments). The author does it in `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidDisappear` methods since `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` are not always called correctly in many applications.
It's your choice.

If you want to be sure to remove observers in the right way unregister it in `dealloc` method or when the view is fully unloaded as you wrote in the second comment.
But be sure that `dealloc` will be call in the future. In other words, as I already mentioned, if the controller continues to stay alive since some other object has a referenced to it, the method will never get called. In this case the controller continues to receive notifications.

Comment: Thanks. But as you mention; 'viewDidUnload is not called before dealloc method. Sometimes a VC's dealloc will be called without viewDidUnload being called and, in this situation, using your suggestion means the VC is left as an observer after it is deallocated as viewWillDisappear / viewDidunload will never be called. Or is viewWillDisappear absolutely guaranteed to be called before dealloc?

Comment: @1ndivisible *viewWillDisappear* is called before the view disappears from the screen. It means that when you remove the view's controller from the screen (e.g. the controller is popped from a navigation controller) that method is called. I added an edit for you.

Comment: Nice. The avoid-nsnotification-removeobserver link is a nice one. Had no idea.

Comment: You should be sure that `dealloc` is called irrespective of whether you're using notifications or not! Given that if your program is working correctly then it will certainly be called when the object is being released, `dealloc` is the best place for unregistering, which makes `init` (or a variant thereof) the only place for registering.

Comment: @mcmahon yes you are right. I added an edit for this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I still don't fully understand why, but adding and removing an observer in viewWillAppear/Disappear would sometimes crash my app. Moving them into viewDidAppear/Disappear fixed it for me.

Comment: It's worth noting that viewDidUnload is deprecated and not called since iOS6! I've edited the answer to add a note about this.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self .........]
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self .........];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For folks stumbling on this page more recently, the removal of observers might not be necessary anymore. The ["Discussion" section of the `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver) say:

> If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its `dealloc` method. Otherwise, you should call `removeObserver(_:name:object:)` before observer or any object passed to this method is deallocated.

Comment: Well thanks for that. I was having an issue where my viewWillDisappear was being called without viewWillAppear, and it was crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not do it in `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidDisappear`? You only care about the notifications when your view is showing anyway, right?

Comment: But as far as I'm aware there is no guarantee that viewDidDisappear is called if the object is deallocated. If it isn't, the object is left as an observer after it is deallocated.

Comment: Apparently they will always be called. (See above)

Comment: No in certain applications one cares about when the view is not showing either i.e update data state

Comment: If the address book is updated while the app is in the background or even if my app is in another view I still want a notification. Thus viewDidDisappear is not suitable.

Comment: No I also care about a view that is covered up by another view

Answer (score 0):

You can addObserver in viewWillAppear,and removeObserver in viewWillDisappear.
but viewWillAppear may called many times. so you can remove Notification first then addObserver.

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification"object:nil];
 }

 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];
 }
```