# iOS Remove observer from notification: Can I call this once for all observers? And even if there are none?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm registering three observers in most of my view controllers. Some have more, some less but I want to include part of the registration and unregistration process in a parent class. Is there any problem with calling the unregistering even if there is no observer? And is one call to unregister enough for all three observers?

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //Has to be unregistered always, otherwise nav controllers down the line will call this method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, that will remove all registrations where the observer is `self`.  It's documented in the [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/removeObserver:):

> The following example illustrates how to unregister `someObserver` for all notifications for which it had previously registered:
>
> ```
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:someObserver];
> ```

Note that in theory (but not, as far as I know, in practice as of iOS 7.0), `UIViewController` could have its own registrations that it doesn't want removed in `viewWillDisappear:`.  It's unlikely to register for any of the notifications in the public API using `addObserver:selector:name:object:`, because that would preclude you registering for them in your `UIViewController` subclass, but it could certainly register for non-public notifications now or in a future version.

A safe way to deregister is to send `removeObserver:name:object:` once for each registration:

```
- (void)deregisterForKeyboardNotifications {
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [center removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [center removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self deregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self deregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
}
```

Another way is to use `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` to register (instead of `addObserver:selector:name:object:`).  This returns a new observer object reference for each registration.  You have to save these away (perhaps in an `NSArray` instance variable if you don't want to create individual instance variables).  Then you pass each one to `removeObserver:` to deregister its notification.  Example:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    NSMutableArray *observers;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    __weak MyViewController *me = self;
    observers = [NSMutableArray array];
    [observers addObject:[center addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
        object:nil queue:queue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            [me keyboardWillShow:note];
        }]];
    [observers addObject:[center addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
        object:nil queue:queue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            [me keyboardWillHide:note];
        }]];
    [observers addObject:[center addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
        object:nil queue:queue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            [me applicationWillResignActive:note];
        }]];
}

- (void)deregisterForKeyboardNotifications {
    for (id observer in observers) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer];
    }
    observers = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self deregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self deregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
}
```

Since every observer returned by `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` is a new object that has only one registration, each call to `removeObserver:` is guaranteed to only remove that observer's one registration.

#### Update for iOS 9 / macOS 10.11 and later

As of iOS 9 and macOS 10.11, `NSNotificationCenter` automatically deregisters an observer if the observer is deallocated. It is no longer necessary to deregister yourself manually in your `dealloc` method (or `deinit` in Swift) if your deployment target is iOS 9 or later or macOS 10.11 or later.

Comment: Ok thx. But this is only theory? Or is there a reasonable danger that I could remove some important observers? How would you differentiate then between your observers and iOS observers?

Comment: As I said, as far as I know, `UIViewController` doesn't actually use any notifications as of iOS 7.0.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Very valuable post. Thx alot. And if I remove the observers more specifically as you mentioned with [center removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil] it isn't a problem either if they were never added?

Comment: Correct.  That will not be a problem.

Comment: Hi anyone can explain this related to iOS, My app was getting crashed because of observers and after I removed the observer its not now. I'm adding a controller as an observer to some view. Is it for `NotificationCenter` only?

Answer (score 7):

For your first Question unregistering even when there is no observer is OK.
But for the way you're removing the observer, `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:someObserver];` will remove even the super class observers which is highly unrecommended (except in dealloc because the object is unloaded) but in `viewWillDisappear` you should remove the observers one by one by using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];`